# Prevent a event from propagating further using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit" />

$('#button1').bind('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert('Loading, please wait...');
});
```

However, the `alert` message is not prevented from showing up. How can the event be stopped before `alert`.

Comment: you need to use return

Comment: The event is stopped (from propagating) before the `alert` already - by using the event methods you used. The `return` will stop this very event callback function from executing further. Sorry for being finicky here ;)

Comment: e.stopPropagation stops the propagation of events which are default to it. Best example is a anchor event. Its default action is window.href.location but with e.stopPropagation you avoid the call to it and make some code run on clicking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `return false;`  for what are you trying to do here..

```
$('#button1').bind('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); //stops propogation of click to parent elements
    return false; //stops further execution
    alert('Loading, please wait...');
});
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qFU7/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#button1').bind('click', function(e){
        return false;
        alert('Loading, please wait...');
    });
```

Use this.